# Mongo and Java read nested documents values

Tags: java, json, mongodb

My mongo collections contains following documents

```
{

"syslog": [
    {
        "alertId": "N/A",
        "time": "06:46:57",
        "device": "10.10.20.1"
    },
    {
        "alertId": "N/A",
        "time": "06:47:30",
        "device": "10.10.20.2"
    }
]
}
```

now I want to read only values of given device.

Suppose if I set device="10.10.20.2" it will shows only `"alertId": "N/A",
            "time": "06:47:30",
            "device": "10.10.20.2"` for this I write java code as below

```
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();                                       

criteria.put("syslog.device","10.10.20.2");
DBCursor cur = coll.find(criteria);
while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
    String json = cur.next().toString(); 
}//end of while
```

When I print json it shows me whole json values. How I should find only selected values of given device?

Comment: What do you mean with `When I print json it shows me whole json values` ?

Comment: dont print the whole JSON, pick the fields you want before you convert it to string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator to project array fields. You should update your query as follows :

```
db.collection.find({"syslog.device" : "10.10.20.2"},{syslog : {$elemMatch : {device : "10.10.20.2"}}})
```

In Java :

```
BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();                                       
criteria.put("syslog.device","10.10.20.2");

BasicDBObject elemMatchObj = new BasicDBObject();
elemMatchObj.put("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("device", "10.10.20.2"));

DBCursor cur = coll.find(criteria, new BasicDBObject("syslog", elemMatchObj));
while(cur.hasNext() && !isStopped()) {
    String json = cur.next().toString(); 
}//end of while
```